# I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy Gorilla. Mysql packages aren't installing/updating

Tags: package-management, mysql

Mysql works flawlessly. But, these packets which have been kept back have messed up with apt package manager.

```
The following packages have been kept back:  
mysql-client mysql-server 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Mysql "apt-cache policy mysql-client mysql-server" as requested by @popey

```
apt-cache policy mysql-client mysql-server                   
mysql-client:
  Installed: 8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04
  Candidate: 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.10.2
  Version table:
     8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.10.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security/main i386 Packages
 *** 8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.0.21-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/main i386 Packages
mysql-server:
  Installed: 8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04
  Candidate: 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.10.2
  Version table:
     8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.10.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security/main i386 Packages
 *** 8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.0.21-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `apt-cache policy mysql-client mysql-server`

Comment: @popey updated the apt-cache policy for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the official MySQL repo was disabled on upgrade from **Ubuntu Focal Fossa** to **Ubuntu Groovy Gorilla**.

Re-enabling the repo from **Software & Updates** did the trick.

Thank you, everyone, for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and got the result you described in your question.
This is most likely the issue:

In order to upgrade the mentioned packages, other packages need to be uninstalled (dependency issues most of the time). Since this is a thing the user potentially does not want, it doesn't happen automatically.

In order to upgrade the packages, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Check the output for packages to remove. If you're OK with removing the packages, proceed.

Comment: It is still showing the same message.

Comment: What do you see if you `apt install mysql-client mysql-server` - please paste the entire output.